# custom php function what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to pass a variable through a function. Specifically marks to grades. I got to this stage and exhausted a few pages of searching. Can't seem to get it. I know its going to be simple. Any ideas?

```
function grades ($mark){
    if ($mark > 16 && $mark < 21){
      $grade = 'Grade A';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 12 && $mark < 17){
      $grade = 'Grade B';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 8 && $mark < 13){
      $grade = 'Grade C';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 4 && $mark < 9){
      $grade = 'Grade D';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 0 && $mark < 5){
      $grade = 'Grade E';
    }
    else {
      $grade = 'Not Entered or Out of Range';
    }
    return $grade;
}
```

Comment: You are not returning the `$grade` from the function. Add `return $grade;` before the last `}`

Comment: thank you, but still no go. I have just commented out the function line and the rest works. Is there something wrong with my first line>

Comment: I hope you are calling like this... `echo grades(9);` See the working [**code**](https://eval.in/148581)

Comment: Thanks Shankar... haven't got to that stage yet... my page breaks with what is above. If I comment out the function and leave the if's its OK. I assume it is the first line... I would call it like echo grades($row[somemysqlrow]);

Comment: Your code is working fine as per the demo I attached on my previous comment. (_after adding the return keyword_)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code: http://codepad.org/iZQUENK5

Comment: Thanks Shankar, must be something else... Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function grades ($mark){
    if ($mark > 16 && $mark < 21){
      $grade = 'Grade A';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 12 && $mark < 17){
      $grade = 'Grade B';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 8 && $mark < 13){
      $grade = 'Grade C';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 4 && $mark < 9){
      $grade = 'Grade D';
    }
    elseif ($mark > 0 && $mark < 5){
      $grade = 'Grade E';
    }
    else {
      $grade = 'Not Entered or Out of Range';
    }

    return $grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine maybe the issue is in calling

```
<?php
    function grades ($mark){
        if ($mark > 16 && $mark < 21){
          $grade = 'Grade A';
        }
        elseif ($mark > 12 && $mark < 17){
          $grade = 'Grade B';
        }
        elseif ($mark > 8 && $mark < 13){
          $grade = 'Grade C';
        }
        elseif ($mark > 4 && $mark < 9){
          $grade = 'Grade D';
        }
        elseif ($mark > 0 && $mark < 5){
          $grade = 'Grade E';
        }
        else {
          $grade = 'Not Entered or Out of Range';
        }
        return $grade;
    }

    echo grades(7);
        //Output is : Grade D
?>
```